# Why does IE11 push down my sticky footer out of the viewport in flex?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm starting to learn Flex but after about 3 hours I ran into problems when looking at my website from Internet Explorer.

The problem is the footer, it's supposed to be a sticky footer and it is somewhat, but IE11 pushes the footer out of the viewport vertically. Why?

My index.html

```
<div class="app">
<div class="header">
<a href="#" class="logo">Sitename</a>
<div class="nav">
<a href="#">About</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="main">
<p>Ingen content.</p>  
</div>
</div>
<div class="footer">
Copyright &copy; <a href="http://#">Sitename</a> av @<a href="#">Site</a>
</div>
```

My styles.css

```
 html, body {
 height: 100%;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 }
 body {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #0d0d0d;
 display: -webkit-box;
 display: -moz-box;
 display: -ms-flexbox;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-direction: column;
 -moz-flex-direction: column;
 -ms-flex-direction: column;    
 flex-direction: column;
 color: #fdfdfd;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 }
 *, *:before, *:after {
 box-sizing: inherit;
 }
 .app {
 -webkit-box-flex: 1 0 auto;
 -moz-box-flex: 1 0 auto;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
 -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
 flex: 1 0 auto;
 }

 .header {
 padding-top: 8px;
 background: #333;
 height: 40px;
 }

 .logo {
 font-family: 'Black Ops One', cursive;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: 400;
 font-size: 28px;
 margin-left: 25px;
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
 }
 .logo:hover {
 letter-spacing: 2px;
 }
 .nav {
 float: right;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 25px;
 padding-top: 5px;
 }
 .navlink {
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: white;
 padding-left: 10px;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 }
 .footer {
 /*position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;*/
 -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
 -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
 -ms-flex: 0;
 flex-shrink: 0;
 text-align: center;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
 }

 .main {
 text-align: left;
 }

 .aside-1 {
 background: gold;
 }

 .aside-2 {
 background: hotpink;
 }

 @media all and (min-width: 600px) {
 .aside {
 -webkit-box-flex: 1 0 0;
 -moz-box-flex: 1 0 0;
 -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
 -ms-flex: 1 0 0;
 flex: 1 0 0;
 }
 }

 @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
 .main    {
 -webkit-box-flex: 3 0px;
 -moz-box-flex: 3 0px;
 -webkit-flex: 3 0px;
 -ms-flex: 3 0px;
 flex: 3 0px;
 }
 .aside-1 { 
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  order: 1; 
  } 
  .main    { 
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
   -ms-flex-order: 2;
   -webkit-order: 2;
   order: 2; 
   }
   .aside-2 { 
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 3;
   -ms-flex-order: 3;
   -webkit-order: 3;
   order: 3; 
   }
  .footer  { 
   -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
   -moz-box-ordinal-group: 4;
   -ms-flex-order: 4;
   -webkit-order: 4;
   order: 4; 
   }
   }
```

I've checked several websites, including stackoverflow and this code seems to be correct but for some reason it's not rendering the page as expected in IE11 (pushes the sticky footer out of the vertical viewport).

Comment: it's possible that the issue is simply that the `body` has a margin set by default, so if you set that to `0`, there shouldn't be a scrollbar

Comment: @Scrimothy the body has no margin or padding, I've used CSS reset 2. Do you have any other ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: Oh, when using `flex-direction: column` in IE11, you need to set a `height` on that element because IE has issues setting the height in that scenario (even if you have a `min-height` defined). If you give your body a `height: 100%`, that _should_ fix it. https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `flex-direction: column` in IE11, you need to set a `height` on that element because IE has issues setting the height in that scenario (even if you have a `min-height` defined). If you give your body a `height: 100vh`, that should fix it.

If you don't want your footer to *always* be visible on the bottom, you'll want to wrap all your elements in a div and set your current `body` flex styles onto that. This way you'll be able to use `min-height` on the `body` and still add a definite `height: 100%` on your app wrapper div.

See this site for more detailed info on all flex bugs:
https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-3

Here's an example snippet in the most simplest form. Generally, I haven't put flex layouts directly on the html or body elements. Not sure if this cause issues or not. The biggest difference from your structure is that I use the `.app` to wrap everything including the footer, so that I can apply flex styling on that, and use the `.main` as the flexible element that pushes the footer to the bottom.

```css
html,body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

header,
footer {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}


/* presentation only */
header,
footer {
  background: salmon;
  padding: 12px;
}

.main {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <header> header</header>
  <div class="main"> main </div>
  <footer>footer</footer>
 </div>
```

Comment: html, body is set to height: 100% already, and body is also set to min-height:100vh. Doesn't work. Could you give me an example of how you meant I should implement this with the code above?